# Using mgsub function with word boundaries for replacement values

Tags: regex, r, qdap, character-replacement

I am trying to replace substrings of string elements within a vector with blank spaces. Below are the vectors we are considering:

```
test <- c("PALMA DE MALLORCA", "THE RICH AND THE POOR", "A CAMEL IN THE DESERT", "SANTANDER SL", "LA")

lista <- c("EL", "LA", "ES", "DE", "Y", "DEL", "LOS", "S.L.", "S.A.", "S.C.", "LAS",
       "DEL", "THE", "OF", "AND", "BY", "S", "L", "A", "C", "SA", "SC", "SL")
```

Then if we apply the `mgsub` function as it is, we get the following output:

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(lista, "", test)
# [1] "PM MOR"   "RIH POOR" "M IN ERT" "NTER"     ""
```

So I change my list to the following and reexecute:

```
lista <- paste("\\b", lista, "\\b", sep = "")
mgsub(lista, "", test)
# [1] "PALMA DE MALLORCA"     "THE RICH AND THE POOR" "A CAMEL IN THE DESERT"
# [4] "SANTANDER SL"          "LA"
```

I cannot get the word boundary regex to work for this function.

Comment: First, try `lista <- paste("(?<!\\w)", lista, "(?!\\w)", sep = "")` and then `mgsub(lista, "", test, perl=TRUE)`. Word boundaries won't work for all the items in `lista`, those that end with `.`.

Comment: @stribizhev tried it but still doesn't extract the elements in test from the pattern lista

Comment: @stribizhev I removed all punctuation, but I still can't get it to function. Any ideas?

Comment: The default `fixed = TRUE` is likely what is causing issue.  Use `fixed = FALSE`.  As in: `mgsub(lista, "", test, fixed=FALSE); ##[1] "PALMA MALLORCA"  "RICH POOR"       "CAMEL IN DESERT" "SANTANDER"       "" `

Comment: @TylerRinker that was exactly the issue, I didn't understand that argument fully before, and I set it as TRUE. Thanks

Comment: @MNBeitelmal: According to [documenation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/multigsub), `fixed=TRUE` is really a culprit. However, you still need to handle list items like `S.A.`, right? Did you test them with my approach or still `\\b` works best for you?

Comment: @stribizhev "\\b" worked for my purposes, but I was interested to try your approach so I did. Is "(?!\\w)" some kinf regex?

Comment: `(?!\w)` is a negative look-ahead that will fail a match (=no match will be found) if a word character appears after the current position in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`multigsub {qdap}` documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/multigsub):

> `mgsub(pattern, replacement = NULL, text.var, leadspace = FALSE,
>     trailspace = FALSE, fixed = TRUE, trim = TRUE, ...)`
>   ...
>   **`fixed`**
>   logical. If `TRUE`, pattern is a string to be matched as is. Overrides all conflicting arguments.

To make sure your vector of search terms is parsed as regular expressions, you need to "manually" set the `fixed` parameter to `FALSE`.

Another important note: the word boundary set after `.` requires a word character after it (or end of line). It is safer to use `(?!\w)` subpattern in this case. To use look-arounds in R regex, you need to use Perl-like regex. Thus, I suggest using this (if a non-word character can appear only at the end of the regex):

```
lista <- paste("\\b", lista, "(?!\\w)", sep = "")
```

or (if there can be a non-word character at the beginning, too):

```
lista <- paste("(?<!\\w)", lista, "(?!\\w)", sep = "")
```

and then

```
mgsub(lista, "", test, fixed=FALSE, perl=TRUE)
```